# WPF, why my BackgroundWorker function only runs one time?

Tags: c#, wpf, function, backgroundworker

I have a function that i want to run it every 1 second and beside that i do have other stuff , 
because im using Thread on my other function and avoiding Window Crashes i decided to use Backgroundworker to call the function that suppose to run like this:

```
Main()
{
    BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWork);
    worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}

public void worker_DoWork(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AutoChecking(); // thats a function should Run on Background every 1 second
}

public void AutoChecking()
{
    this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(() =>
    {
        if (SystemisGood == true)
            Updatecolor.Fill = Green;
        else
            Updatecolor.Fill = Red;
    }));
}
```

However this function only works one time now any reason or solution to make it work every one second and Stay with backgroundworker ?!
P.S: i dont want to use Timer...

Comment: Why don't you want to use a timer? That's what they are for.

Comment: i rather to use this only because Timer will block my main function thread...

Comment: Could you post the code how to use Timer which block your UI? Use backgroundworker as a timer is not really good way to go

Comment: System.Timers.Timer CheckTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
   CheckTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(CheckTimer_Elapsed);
   CheckTimer.Start();

Comment: @CuongLe Check the comment thats how i used my timer

Comment: Given that all that happens in your background worker is a call to marshal back to the UI thread, I suggest using `DispatcherTimer` to invoke the callback on the UI thread directly. `Timers.Timer` does that only if you set the `SynchronizingObject`.

Comment: @mikez Never used dispacher can you tel me how have to introduce it instead of  Timer?

Comment: dispatcherTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
 dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(Timer);
dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
dispatcherTimer.Start();

Comment: @mikez thats how i used dispacher but its still a same problem

Comment: @PublicAffair If you don't tell us exactly what the problem is we can't really suggest any solutions.

Comment: He has some other problem with his code that he isn't posting.  He claims my simple 10/sec time check loop below is freezing his window.  Obviously something else is because 10 time checks per second in a background thread is not going to freeze anything.

Comment: Problem appear When im trying to move The Window Around my Screen, in second i touch drag it to move the whole program hanging

Comment: @PublicAffair so you are doing something on the UI thread that is blocking.

Answer (score 1):

It is wasteful to not use a timer, since those are very lightweight and just send a periodic message, but you could accomplish what you want by using a low overhead polling loop and checking the time, much as what is done by the timer code itself.  For example:

```
Main()
{
    BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWork);
    worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}

bool exitBGThread = false;

public void worker_DoWork(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TimeSpan interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
    while (!exitBGThread)
    {
        DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
        AutoChecking();  // thats a function should Run on Background every 1 second

        while (!exitBGThread)
        {
            DateTime cur = DateTime.Now;
            if (cur - start >= interval)
                break;
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }
}

public void AutoChecking()
{
    this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(() =>
    {
        if (SystemisGood  == true )
             Updatecolor.Fill = Green;
        else 
             Updatecolor.Fill = Red;
    }));
}
```

This is a bit simplified as you would want to use lock { } if you actually used exitBGThread, but you get the idea.

Comment: Its welldone code but still its freeze my window once im trying to move the window around screen abit

Comment: There's no way this code freezes your window.  It's running in a background thread and it's very low latency -- it does a simple time check about 10 times per second.

Comment: Maybe he's doing some lengthy synchronous operation in his SystemIsGood property to check if the system is good :)....yes naughty...in which case it needs to be moved into the BackgroundWorker thread

Comment: @colinsmith, that is an excellent guess.  It could also be that an unrelated piece of code is UI thread blocking.  In any event it is not the low latency background thread which consumes less than 1 msec per second.  I answered his actual question, but he wants his code debugged without even posting it.